# Goroutines and Channels with Multiple Types

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I'm relatively new to Go and trying to figure out the best way to concurrently pull information from a `REST API`. The intent is to make multiple concurrent calls to an `API`, with each call returning a different type of data.

I currently have:

```
s := NewClient()
c1 := make(chan map[string]Service)
c2 := make(chan map[string]ServicePlan)
c3 := make(chan map[string]ServiceInstance)
c4 := make(chan map[string]ServiceBinding)
c5 := make(chan map[string]Organization)
c6 := make(chan map[string]Space)

go func() {
    c1 <- GetServices(s)
}()

go func() {
    c2 <- GetServicePlans(s)
}()

go func() {
    c3 <- GetServiceInstances(s)
}()

go func() {
    c4 <- GetServiceBindings(s)
}()

go func() {
    c5 <- GetOrganizations(s)
}()

go func() {
    c6 <- GetSpaces(s)
}()

services := <- c1
servicePlans := <- c2
serviceInstances := <- c3
serviceBindings := <- c4
orgs := <- c5
spaces := <- c6
// stitch all the data together later
```

but I was wondering if there was a better way to write this.

EDIT: It's still ugly, but reduced the number of channels to one:

```
c := make(chan interface{})

var (
    services     map[string]Service
    servicePlans     map[string]ServicePlan
    serviceInstances map[string]ServiceInstance
    serviceBindings  map[string]ServiceBinding
    orgs         map[string]Organization
    spaces       map[string]Space
)

go func() {
    c <- GetServices(s)
}()

go func() {
    c <- GetServicePlans(s)
}()

go func() {
    c <- GetServiceInstances(s)
}()

go func() {
    c <- GetServiceBindings(s)
}()

go func() {
    c <- GetOrganizations(s)
}()

go func() {
    c <- GetSpaces(s)
}()

for i := 0; i < 6; i++ {
    v := <-c
    switch v := v.(type) {
    case map[string]Service:
        services = v
    case map[string]ServicePlan:
        servicePlans = v
    case map[string]ServiceInstance:
        serviceInstances = v
    case map[string]ServiceBinding:
        serviceBindings = v
    case map[string]Organization:
        orgs = v
    case map[string]Space:
        spaces = v
    }
}
```

I would still really like a way to do this so I don't have to hard-code that the loop needs to run 6 times. I actually tried make a list of functions to run and doing it that way to remove the repetitive `go func` calls, but since all the functions have different return types, I got all type mismatch errors, and you can't fake it by using `func(api) interface{}` either as that just creates a runtime panic.

Comment: It looks like you might be over-using channels. If the requests are already concurrent and each return a single type of result, why do you need even more goroutines and channels to receive the result?

Comment: That's the trick though, each returns a different type of result

Comment: You could assign the values in a closures: http://play.golang.org/p/Sak5QGCPZi, or you can do as suggested below and use  a generic interface{} to receive any type.

Comment: Question about that: I thought you had to use channels instead of doing direct assignments inside of the goroutine. Is that not true?

Comment: No, dispatching closures as goroutines is very idiomatic. You always have to ensure that you never have concurrent reads and writes, but here the WaitGroup provides synchronization.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When I see this, I think we may be conflating assignment with completion, thus creating one channel per type.

It may be simpler to create one closure per type for assignment and a single channel to manage completion.

example:

```
s := NewClient()
c := make(chan bool)
// I don't really know the types here
var services services
var servicePlans servicePlans
var serviceInstances serviceInstances
var serviceBindings serviceInstances
var orgs orgs
var spaces spaces

go func() {
    service = GetServices(s)
    c <- true
}()

go func() {
    servicePlans = GetServicePlans(s)
    c <- true
}()

go func() {
    serviceInstances = GetServiceInstances(s)
    c <- true
}()

go func() {
    serviceBindings = GetServiceBindings(s)
    c <- true
}()

go func() {
    orgs = GetOrganizations(s)
    c <- true
}()

go func() {
    spaces = GetSpaces(s)
    c <- true
}()

for i = 0; i < 6; i++ {
    <-c
}
// stitch all the data together later
```

The Go authors anticipated this use-case, and provide the sync.WaitGroup which makes this a little clearer [sync.WaitGroup Docs](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) Underneath it is fancy atomic operations which replace the channel synchronization.

example:

```
s := NewClient()
// again, not sure of the types here
var services services
var servicePlans servicePlans
var serviceInstances serviceInstances
var serviceBindings serviceInstances
var orgs orgs
var spaces spaces

var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(6)

go func() {
    service = GetServices(s)
    wg.Done()
}()

go func() {
    servicePlans = GetServicePlans(s)
    wg.Done()
}()

go func() {
    serviceInstances = GetServiceInstances(s)
    wg.Done()
}()

go func() {
    serviceBindings = GetServiceBindings(s)
    wg.Done()
}()

go func() {
    orgs = GetOrganizations(s)
    wg.Done()
}()

go func() {
    spaces = GetSpaces(s)
    wg.Done()
}()

// blocks until all six complete
wg.Wait()
// stitch all the data together later
```

I hope this is helps.

Comment: I think this is the most complete example I've seen so far. I ended up using the WaitGroup example and it works perfectly.

Comment: I like the use of wait group here. Is there a way to repeat yourself less though? Like creating a slice of functions and then looping over them?

Answer (score 7):

You might find it easier to create a single channel of type `interface{}` which will allow you to send any value. Then, on the receiving end, you can perform a type assertion for a specific type:

```
c := make(chan interface{})

/* Sending: */
c <- 42
c <- "test"
c <- &ServicePlan{}

/* Receiving */
something := <-c
switch v := something.(type) {
case int:          // do something with v as an int
case string:       // do something with v as a string
case *ServicePlan: // do something with v as an instance pointer
default:
}
```

Comment: I had considered a similar approach, but the problem I see is that this only waits for one of the responses to come back, not all of them. I was under the assumption that switch need to be in some kind of for loop with a way to know when that loop should break.

Comment: @RossPeoples you can put the receive/switch code in a `for{}` loop if you need to receive more than one value.

Comment: @RossPeoples, no need to wrap a switch around a for (unless you want to). https://golang.org/ref/spec#Break_statements: A "break" statement terminates execution of the innermost "for", "switch", or "select" statement within the same function.

Comment: It's the for{} loop I'm having trouble with. There's no way that I can see to tell it to break out of the loop. And using range on the channel doesn't work unless you close the channel, and I don't think there's an appropriate place to do that in this example.

Answer (score 0):

You approach is quite meaningful with little disclaimer. In the end part your receive from channels sequentially

```
services := <- c1
servicePlans := <- c2
serviceInstances := <- c3
serviceBindings := <- c4
```

but this make your code synchronous, because

```
go func() {
    c2 <- GetServicePlans(s)
}()
```

can't write to c2 as long as opposite side would read, and it would not before `services := <- c1` execute. So despite been in goroutines code will execute sequentially. Easiest way to make code more async is at least to provide buffered channels

```
c1 := make(chan map[string]Service, 1) //buffered channel with capacity one
```

which allow c1 <- GetServices(s) do it's work and buffer result in channel.

Comment: You are correct. Using multiple channels introduces several possible issues. I modified my answer to include a single channel version which worked well, but I think I'm going to use the WaitGroup version now. Thanks for pointing out synchronous issue!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the `chan interface{]` approach, you might consider creating an envelope object (`APIObject` in the example below) to point to the true value that you wish to send. It comes with memory overheads, but also increased type-safety. (Comments and opinions weighing the two approach would be much appreciated.)

https://play.golang.org/p/1KIZ7Qfg43

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Service struct{ Name string }
type ServicePlan struct{ Name string }
type Organization struct{ Name string }

type APIObject struct {
    Service      *Service
    ServicePlan  *ServicePlan
    Organization *Organization
}

func main() {
    objs := make(chan APIObject)

    go func() {
        objs <- APIObject{Service: &Service{"Service-1"}}
        objs <- APIObject{ServicePlan: &ServicePlan{"ServicePlan-1"}}
        objs <- APIObject{Organization: &Organization{"Organization-1"}}
        close(objs)
    }()

    for obj := range objs {
        if obj.Service != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Service: %v\n", obj.Service)
        }
        if obj.ServicePlan != nil {
            fmt.Printf("ServicePlan: %v\n", obj.ServicePlan)
        }
        if obj.Organization != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Organization: %v\n", obj.Organization)
        }
    }
}
```